# Rotate element thrown outside the SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, transform

I have an SVG chart, part of which is shown below,

```
<div>
   <svg class="bullet svg" width="1142" height="63" id="svg0">
      <g transform="translate(144,35)">
         <text transform="translate(10,10)" x="869.5999999999999" y="-12.5" class="markerText" id="2100">2100</text>
      </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

but as soon as I add a rotate transform to rotate the text, the text just disappears and its position changes

```
<div>
   <svg class="bullet svg" width="1142" height="63" id="svg0">
      <g transform="translate(144,35) rotate(20)">
         <text transform="translate(10,10) rotate(20)" x="869.5999999999999" y="-12.5" class="markerText" id="2100">2100</text>
      </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwct7.png)

How can I rotate the text on its own position and also make it visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
<g transform="translate(144,35)">
         <text transform="translate(10,10) rotate (20)" x="869.5999999999999" y="-12.5" class="markerText" id="2100">2100</text>
      </g>
```

It will rotate about the origin.

So your DOM text center would be:

```
cx = 144 +10 + 869.599;//center x of text DOM..1023.599
cy = 35 +10 + -12.5;//center of y of text DOM..32.5
```

now as you want to rotate about the center of the TEXT dom do:

```
<text transform="translate(10,10) rotate (20 1023 32.5)" ...
```

This will make it ratate the text about 1023,32.5.

**Please note** I am ignoring the text width for center calculation of text DOM.

Comment: If the OP sets "text-anchor" as middle and "dominant-baseline" as central, your answer's calculations will be right in the centre of the text.

Answer (score 2):

To rotate the text around its own centre, use:

```
rotate(20, cx, cy)
```

Where `cx` and `cy` are the positions of the text (including all the "translates").